# ExtJS 4: Change grid's column editor

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a grid with cell editing plugin. one of the columns has combo box editor but I need to change it to text field if the combo box store items are empty at run-time.

How can I change the editor for ONLY that cell with 'cellclick' event on the grid?

I tried to add it with this but it doesn't work.

```
var editor = {
               xtype: 'textfield'
             };
view.editingPlugin.editors= editor;
```

Comment: What did you try? What did not work?

Comment: added it to the question.

Comment: Have you tried  `getEditor` function?